# PHP / XML - distinct values & nested loops

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm in the process of upgrading an old asp Movie theater site to php.  It needs to pull its movie schedule data from an xml feed.

This is schedule.xml:

```
<showtimes>
  <movie>
    <name>BROOKLYN</name>
    <movieId>BR30015</movieId>
    <showtime>
      <date>01082016</date>
      <time>1700</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29779</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01082016</date>
      <time>1930</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29780</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01092016</date>
      <time>1700</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29797</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01092016</date>
      <time>1930</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29796</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01102016</date>
      <time>1700</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29822</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01102016</date>
      <time>1930</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29823</linkref>
    </showtime>
  </movie>
  <movie>
    <name>THE HATEFUL EIGHT</name>
    <movieId>HA18700</movieId>
    <showtime>
      <date>01072016</date>
      <time>1630</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29399</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01072016</date>
      <time>2000</time>
      <soldout>1</soldout>
      <linkref>29400</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01082016</date>
      <time>1800</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29770</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01082016</date>
      <time>2130</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29771</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01082016</date>
      <time>2330</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29799</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01092016</date>
      <time>1800</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29808</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01092016</date>
      <time>2130</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29807</linkref>
    </showtime>
  </movie>
</showtimes>
```

The idea is that there will be a showtimes section in the movie detail page where the user can click on a date / time and be taken directly to the online bookings site for that showing.

The movie is pulled from the xml via movieId tag.
Each movie is shown around 3-5 times a day for at least a week.

If a user selects the Movie THE HATEFUL EIGHT, I need the output to be displayed like this:

```
01072016 - 1630, 2000, 
01082016 - 1800, 2130, 2330
01092016 - 1800, 2130
```

I've looked high and low for a solution, and I seem to be going round in circles.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Nico

Comment: Write some code, use a XML parser like `SimpleXml` or `DOM`, come back with a specific problem ;-) Have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick :)

```
<?php

$xml = "<showtimes>
  <movie>
    <name>BROOKLYN</name>
    <movieId>BR30015</movieId>
    <showtime>
      <date>01082016</date>
      <time>1700</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29779</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01082016</date>
      <time>1930</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29780</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01092016</date>
      <time>1700</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29797</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01092016</date>
      <time>1930</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29796</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01102016</date>
      <time>1700</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29822</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01102016</date>
      <time>1930</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29823</linkref>
    </showtime>
  </movie>
  <movie>
    <name>THE HATEFUL EIGHT</name>
    <movieId>HA18700</movieId>
    <showtime>
      <date>01072016</date>
      <time>1630</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29399</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01072016</date>
      <time>2000</time>
      <soldout>1</soldout>
      <linkref>29400</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01082016</date>
      <time>1800</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29770</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01082016</date>
      <time>2130</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29771</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01082016</date>
      <time>2330</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29799</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01092016</date>
      <time>1800</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29808</linkref>
    </showtime>
    <showtime>
      <date>01092016</date>
      <time>2130</time>
      <soldout>0</soldout>
      <linkref>29807</linkref>
    </showtime>
  </movie>
</showtimes>";

function getMovieNode($name, $xmlString) {
  $movies = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
  foreach ($movies as $movie) {
    if ($movie->name == $name) return $movie;
  }
  throw new Exception('Movie not found');
}

function convertNodes($nodes) {
  $times = [];
  foreach ($nodes as $time) {
    array_push($times, $time);
  }
  return $times;
}

function getSchedule($name, $xmlString) {
  $movie = getMovieNode($name, $xmlString);
  return array_reduce(convertNodes($movie->showtime), function($acc, $curr) {
    $acc[reset($curr->date)][] = reset($curr->time);
    return $acc;
  }, []);
}

foreach (getSchedule('THE HATEFUL EIGHT', $xml) as $date => $times) {
  print $date;
  print ' - ';
  $last = array_pop($times);
  foreach ($times as $time) {
    print $time;
    print ', ';
  }
  print $last . "\n";
}
```

Comment: some details as to why your solution *should do the trick* is in order. The rest of us would greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: "Should do the trick" implicitly means "Does the trick"...?

1. xml is parsed with simplexml_load_string()
2. the nodes look like an array and can be traversed like one, but the type is not Array - hence the convertNodes() function
3. array_reduce is used to build up the correct array structure for every date
4. the build structure is looped over and printed to the screen

Comment: I don't believe it does, no. I do however believe an answer should be accompanied with some sort of explanation or details as to why it does or should work. And if **should** is the word of choice, in what circumstances it would, in effect, produce the expected result in the OP's question. See here about [code only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)

Comment: Now, if you will edit your answer to include the info from the comment I will be the first to upvote :)

Comment: Thanks @DavidWickström that worked like a charm. My code editor didn't like the syntax of a couple of lines:  this:    $times = [];  and this:    }, []);  If I wanted to fetch the xml in via a cached file on my server, what would I need to change?  Many Thanks  Nico

Comment: @Niconedz Maybe your code editor is not liking the ["new" array syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)? A little strange since it's not exactly new any longer? If you wanted to fetch the xml from an http server, there are plenty of options, but you could try this simple approach: `$xml = file_get_contents('http://server/resource/address'); // instead of $xml = "<showtimes>..."`

Comment: Yep, worked brilliantly.   Thanks again @DavidWickström